# Virtual Box - Win 2K8 Guest cannot connect to Internet

Tags: virtualbox

Good Day,

I am running Windows 7 as my host OS and running Win2K8 as my guest OS and am trying to get the guest to connect to the Internet.  I can ping the internal IP address of the host from the guest.  Here is the information from the guest OS.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : WIN-QFAG77EA1B2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-55-4D-17
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e4f7:ff93:681f:53b0%10(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.15(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Monday, May 02, 2011 10:31:56 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, May 03, 2011 10:31:57 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.2.2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.21.2.16
                                       172.21.2.11
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I've read the documentation, but I'm a total newbie when it comes to networks.  So I can only assume that this looks OK.  I've enabled NAT (which according to my understanding) should satisfy most needs.

What else can I try to make this work?

TIA,

coson

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions in the Win2K8 system?

Comment: No, I didn't realize that guest additions would matter.  Like I said, I'm a total noob ;)

Comment: @Coson no problem, and yeah, the guest additions include some interesting bits 'n' pieces - like network adapters.  If you've a software firewall on your host PC this'll need some configuration as well.